# Instrumenting lines of a method

Tags: java, instrumentation

I need to programmatically instrument the lines of code of a method so that I can know what lines were touched or not by a certain execution - I want to have a map between the line numbers and if they were run or not.

So far, I have been using [JaCoCo](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/) to perform this instrumentation. But JaCoCo instruments the whole class and I want to have control of what methods are instrumented.

Can I do this with libraries like [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/), [BCEL](http://commons.apache.org/bcel/) or [javassist](http://www.jboss.org/javassist)? If so, can anyone point me to some documentation or tutorial?

Comment: So you want to be able to turn of instrumentation for some methods of your class?

Comment: Have you thought about using cobertura, which does that natively?

Comment: @RogerLindsjö Yes, I want to turn of instrumentation for some methods, is it possible? I also want to be able to know the line numbers of each statement, so that I can fill that map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at [Cobertura source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sourceforge.cobertura/cobertura/1.9.4/net/sourceforge/cobertura/instrument/ClassInstrumenter.java?av=f) (that itself uses [ASM](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.5/org.objectweb/asm/3.1.0/org/objectweb/asm/MethodAdapter.java?av=f)). It is not a tutorial, but on the other hand, it is a real world example, and not a toy.

Answer (score 0):

There are many code coverage tools, many have IDE integration so you can easily generate these reports by running the program.  You can also use maven to generate the reports.

The simplest solution is to find an open source code coverage tool which does what you want and enhance it and perhaps the developers of the tool will take your improvements.

Here is a list of thirteen cover coverage related tools to get you started.
http://www.java-sources.com/open-source/code-coverage